# c++ - _mkdir giving false errors windows

Tags: c++, error-handling, mkdir, errno

Hi I am trying to make a directory in windows with this code

header

```
#include <direct.h>
```

script

```
int main() {
    string local = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Mail";   

    try
    {
        _mkdir (local.c_str ());
        cout << "It is made?";
    }

    catch(invalid_argument& e)
    {
        cout << e.what () << " " << (char*) EEXIST;
        if (e.what () == (char*) EEXIST) {
            cout << e.what () << " " << (char*) EEXIST;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

The file is clearly not made, but it is also not making [the error it should.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fkk4dzw.aspx)

Comment: You're ignoring the return value.

Comment: I know I don't have permissions, but the problem I am having is that the file isn't made, but it isn't being catched. Also @tkausl are you talking about at the end of the catch? I tried to set return to -1 but I get "return value type does not match the function type" Is there another value I should set it to? (I am pretty knew to try/catch)

Comment: oh yeah main, I kinda grabbed the code from another function and stuck it into main for this question... forgot to place return appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_mkdir` won't throw an exception. (This is not python or boost, or any smart middleware)

Read the documentation you were referring to: it returns a value. 0 is OK, -1: error, ask why to `errno`

Don't ignore the return value. You probably have insufficient rights without UAC elevation to create the directory.

Comment: Mmmhhh I am still not quite super clear on this. The document said "On an error, the function returns –1 and sets errno as follows." so how would I check errno? and I was getting an error on catch when I returned -1(If that is the return value you mean). I guess I should have put that the cout in catch is never run, only the one in try is.

Answer (score 2):

So I finally figured errno out, which for errno you need the `<errno.h>` header. The complete list of [errno codes](http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno).

If you want to see what errno code something is throwing lets say

```
if (
    _mkdir(((string)"C:/Program Files (x86)/Mail").c_str()) == 0 ||
    errno == 17 /* this is the code for - File exists - */
){
    // Do stuff

} else {
    int errorCode = errno; // You need to save the code before anything else,
                           //    because something else might change its value
    cout << errorCode;
}
```

Comment: `_mkdir(((string)"C:/Program Files (x86)/Mail").c_str())` is useless, just do `_mkdir("C:/Program Files (x86)/Mail")`